# Is there a web application that helps with the download of a static website for offline viewing later?

Tags: webapp-rec, offline

Is there a web application that can download a complete web page so I can view it offline?

Comment: you mean something like the offline-mode of your browser? you mean a (web)service which grabs the page and give it to you in some way?

Answer (score 1):

**[htTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)** is a free (GPL, libre/free software)

Comment: that is not a webapp.

Comment: Wouldn't a web app require that you are connected to the internet? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Short..No, Mainly because Most websites will prevent you from being able to do it.

If you  would go for Single pages the Zotero Plugin for Firefox does a good job.